# RxSwift with CollectionView/TableView Input/ textfields

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to grasp RxSwift, I need to validate form, I have done simple validation without tableView, but now my text input fields are in collection view and i want to observe changes in text inputs, as textfields are now in reusable cell, i'm not sure how to add observables and get stream from them

Basically I want 2 way binding of my data to my form where inputs are dynamic, if that helps

here is code of my cellForItemAt function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RegisterCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! RegisterCell
    var registerField = dataSource[indexPath.item]
    registerField.indexPath = indexPath
    registerField.text = viewModel.getText(indexPath: indexPath)
    let txt = cell.txtfield as UITextField
    txt.delegate = self
    cell.configureCell(registerField)
    return cell
}
```

and configure cell

```
func configureCell(_ fieldData: RegisterFields) {
    txtfield.placeholder = fieldData.placeholderText
    txtfield.isSecureTextEntry = fieldData.isSecureEntry
    txtfield.text = fieldData.text
    txtfield.tag = fieldData.indexPath.item
    imgIcon.image  = fieldData.image
    imgDropDown.isHidden = !fieldData.isDropDown
}
```

I want to use Rx for user inputs instead of delegate pattern as done in following line

> txt.delegate = self

Following is image of my screen

[image]

Comment: i've added all details to know about question, please read question before down vote , Thanks

Comment: Are you binding the table data to the tableview or are you using the normal tableview delegates? or RxDataSource?

Comment: I'm using normal tableview delegate, there is one textfield in cell, i want to listen user input in that textfields

Comment: If you can make your question be reopened, I have the answer you are looking for

Comment: How I can do that?
I've editing my question but it's still on hold

Comment: @ArslanAsim I guess you can add the code of you tableview delegate and the code of your custom cell

Comment: Added both code and image, do have to appeal somewhere?

Comment: @ArslanAsim People who see your question now and deem it ok to be reopened can/will vote to reopen it, as I just did. But it needs five users total, so you may have to wait a bit more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First give your custom cell it's own dispose bag for dealloc purposes

```
import RxSwift

class YourCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

   var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

   @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
}
```

Then in you controller, listen to the textfield input stream:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      guard let cell = cell as? YourCustomCell, textfield = cell.textfield else { return }

      textfield
            .rx.textInput.text.orEmpty
            .asDriver()
            .drive(onNext: { [unowned self] text in
               //do what you want here
            })
            .addDisposableTo(cell.disposeBag)
    }
```

Comment: is it okay to bind this way:
cell?.elementTextField?.rx.text
                    .map{$0 ?? ""}
                    .bind(onNext: { [weak self](text) in
               //do what you want here
                }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

Comment: @TibinThomas You should use a Driver as it forces the use of the main thread. Given a textfield is a UI element, you want events related to it to be treated on the main thread. A Driver can't error out, observes on main scheduler and shares side effects. Which is what you want when dealing with user interface.

Comment: Giving a cell it's own disposable bag helps in preventing a property being subscribed multiple times due to cell reuse of UITableView,which in turn avoids unexpected behaviours in your RxSwift Application.